# Setting general Schema.org offer currency value with Microdata

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have a site with a lot of offers that use the Schema.org `Offer` type.

**Can I somehow set the currency of all the offer prices on my site?** Or do I have to set the `itemprop="priceCurrency"` for each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to set site-wide default values for Microdata properties.

If a single page contains several `Offer` items, you could use Microdata’s `itemref` attribute (see example below). But this does not work across pages.

```html
<head>
  <title>A page with two offers</title>
  <meta id="site-currency" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
  <!-- this 'meta' element can also be part of the 'body' element -->
</head>

<body>

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="site-currency">
  </div>

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="site-currency">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer!